# MS Access: update whole table from form

Tags: ms-access

I have a small table 2*2. I show the values of the form in a continues form. Suppose, it show the values in the form as below

```
fname     lname
-----    ------
adam       jones
terry      jonas
```

For simplicity I kept the table size small. But basically it is 10*10 size table. Anyway, what I want is that, the names that show on the form should be editable. So after showing the form above, I should be able to edit all the names adam, jones, terry, jonas. After editing the names, if user click on update button then all the names in the database table should be updated.

I don't understand how to do this. This is a continuous form. How can I keep track which names are being changed on the form? Or should I update the whole table? Or if I make it single form without being continuous will it help? Please give me some insight so that I know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

A continuous form is by definition a **bound** form, i.e. it is directly connected to a table or query. If you edit a row, and move to another row, or close the form etc., the edited record is saved automatically.

This is standard Access functionality, and you don't need any code (or a "Update" button) for it.

If you want to have more control over the saving of records, you need a different approach. *But you should have a real reason for it, otherwise you are just creating useless code.*

E.g. you can make the continuous form read-only, and on double-click open an unbound single form that loads the values of the current row, and is editable. There you can have a "Update" button that saves the values to the table, and a "Cancel" button that discards the changes.

Or if you want to edit on the continuous form, you can copy the whole table to a temporary table, base your edit form on that, and on "Update" copy the temporary table back to the actual table.